# Setting background on layout overrides listSelector

Tags: android, xml

So, I have a layout (as a row in a ListView) and I have listSelector. This listSelector works fine until I add a background to the layout. I want this background there as the starting background (and will change with listSelector). But once I add a background, the listSelector no longer works and my layout doesn't change colors when I press it (like expected). Why is this? Thanks.

The Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/listview_background"
android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
android:minHeight="140dip"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvTime"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="100dip"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- The border color -->
            <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- The fill color-->
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And the List Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listview_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listview_background" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listview_background"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `listSelector` still "works". However, the problem is that the item view is drawn *on top of it*. Therefore, if it has an opaque background, then the selector is completely hidden.

There are two possible solutions for this:

- You can use `drawSelectorOnTop`, which will draw the selector on top on your view. However, this is only valid if the selector is somewhat transparent (which the default is not).
- Use a `StateListDrawable` as the background that is **transparent** when selected (thus, allowing the selector to be shown).

Check Romain Guy's *World of ListView* talk, he mentions this specifically:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=28m18s
- https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf (Slide 33)